# get maximum date and time in duplicate table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

i want to ask about how to get sort of maximum date and maximum time when there is a lot of duplicate data.

i am using this query to show the data

/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/

```
SELECT  
      trx.[ActivityDate]
      ,trx.ActivityTimeStart
      ,trx.ActivityTimeEnd
      ,trx.[EmployeeID]
      ,trx.[ApprovalStatusID]
      ,mst.[FullName]
  FROM [KairosManagementSystem].[dbo].[Tbl_Trx_TimeSheet] trx
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[Tbl_Mst_Employee] mst
  ON trx.[EmployeeID] = mst.[EmployeeID]
  where datepart(year,trx.[ActivityDate]) between datepart(year, dateadd(year,-1,getdate())) and datepart(year, getdate())
  and
  trx.[ActivityDate] <= getdate()
  and
  trx.EmployeeID = 11460 
order by trx.[ActivityDate] DESC
```

as you can see, the result from this is like this image below.
[image]

the question is how to get the result like this. where i want to get the minimum ActivitityTimeStart and maximum ActivityTimeEnd in respective date

```
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |ActivityDate | ActivityTimeStart | ActivityTimeEnd  | EmployeeID | FullName
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |2017-02-17   | 07:00:00 00:00:00 | 16:00:00 00:00:00| 11460      | Yohanes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want a simple `GROUP BY`?

```
SELECT trx.[ActivityDate], MIN(trx.ActivityTimeStart), MAX(trx.ActivityTimeEnd),
       trx.[EmployeeID], mst.[FullName]
FROM [KairosManagementSystem].[dbo].[Tbl_Trx_TimeSheet] trx INNER JOIN
     [dbo].[Tbl_Mst_Employee] mst
     ON trx.[EmployeeID] = mst.[EmployeeID]
WHERE YEAR(trx.[ActivityDate]) between YEAR(dateadd(year,-1,getdate())) and YEAR(getdate()) and
      trx.[ActivityDate] <= getdate() and
      trx.EmployeeID = 11460 
GROUP BY trx.[ActivityDate], trx.[EmployeeID], mst.[FullName]
ORDER BY trx.[ActivityDate] DESC;
```